# How can i implement AJAX queuing in react-native using fetch

Tags: ajax, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I just have implemented AJAX calls using fetch in react-native.
Implementing queuing of these AJAX calls hasn't been very well implemented.
Can any one help me?

Comment: The questions is not really clear. So you wanna make these requests parallel/sequential?

Comment: I wanna make parallel requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make parallel requests, you can use the fact that `fetch` returns a promise to you, and then you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for completion of all promises.

For example:

```
var urls = ['http://url1.net', 'http://url2.net'];
var requests = [];
urls.forEach((url)=>{
    request = fetch(url); // You can also pass options or any other parameters
    requests.push(request);
});

// Then, wait for all Promises to finish. They will run in parallel
Promise.all(requests).then((results) => {
    // Results will hold an array with the results of each promise.

}).catch((err)=>{
    // Promise.all implements a fail-fast mechanism. If a request fails, the catch method will be called immediately
});
```

I noticed that you added the 'multithreading' tag. It is important to notice that this code won't be doing any threading for you, as JS (generally) runs in only one thread.